# ASP.NET Core 6 Web API / C# : routing, POST method, how to set default param

Tags: c#, post, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, asp.net-mvc-routing

Set routing at top of controller:

```
[Route("api/import/v1")]
[ApiController]
public class ImportController : ControllerBase
{
     // .....
}
```

And setting it on a test function:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost("{id1}/{id2}/{id3}")]
public ActionResult Test(string id1, string id2, string id3)
{
     // .....
}
```

In Postman, if I call:

```
https://localhost:7045/api/import/v1/111/222/333
```

it hits the `POST` method and all is well.

However if the id3 string param is optional how can I set a default value on this?

I have tried:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost("{id1}/{id2}/{id3?}")]
public ActionResult Test(string id1, string id2, string? id3 = "000")
{
     // .....
}
```

and calling

```
https://localhost:7071/api/import/v1/111/222/null
```

but id3 is being set as null.

I also tried

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost("{id1}/{id2}/{id3}")]
public ActionResult Test(string id1, string id2, string? id3 = "000")
{
     // .....
}
```

but I get the same result - `id3` is passed in as null.

Any ideas please?

**UPDATE UPDATE UPDATE**
Just for testing purposes I have added a new function

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost("Test2")]
public ActionResult Test2(string id1, string id2, string? id3 = "000")
{
  // .....
}
```

If I then use postman to call
https://localhost:7045/api/import/v1/Test2?id1=111&id2=111&id3=

this will return as expected
id1 = 111
id2 = 111
id3 = 000

but when I try to call

```
https://localhost:7071/api/import/v1/111/222/
```

I am getting a 404 Not Found

why would it not be working when I try to use routing?

Comment: I test it on dotnet 7 (not 6) and there was no problem. I also doubt that such a bug exists in dotnet 6. I think you should create a new project and test this on it. If it works correctly, it means that there is an issue with your project settings (like `program.cs`) and you should look for the issue.

Comment: Thanks for reply please see update to Q

Comment: I also tested this on **dotnet6** and everything was fine!
You can see the source I tested with in [this link](https://github.com/HamidMolareza/StackOverflow-Answers/tree/main/77497604).
You can clone and test it yourself.

Comment: For example: For `curl -X 'POST' 'http://localhost:3000/api/import/v1/1/22' -H 'accept: */*' -d ''` response was: `{"id1":"1","id2":"22","id3":"000"}` that is OK.

Comment: No, you got it wrong when you would set default route param like `string id3 = "000"` in this scenario if you don't provide the value it would always taken `000` but if you provide any value then `000` would always replaced by the newer value, in your scenario `null`. I think this is the expected behavior. What exactly you are looking for?

Comment: i have check this  `[HttpPost("{id1}/{id2}/{id3?}")]` in .NET7 and .NET8 works fine but with .NET6 it Requere the `id3` i don't know whay !! ... anyway you can just update to .NET8 and get the new performance and features beside solveing this problem.